# Stream .LRF files via webbserver

Tags: html

i've noticed that on LoLReplays webpage you can now stream live games via their program LoLRecorder. I found this code on their page

href="lrf://spectator spectator.eu.lol.riotgames.com 2nHvYdkaSjjqC7f+mtHQeIhFcUSQLFu5 488978485 EUN1 3.01.0.1"

And i've tried a little to stream from my own (already recorded) game. But all i get is unable to find match. My question is: Does anyone here know how this works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> TL;DR; You can't stream anything, but you can open LoLReplay in spectator mode for a specific match.

Try reinstalling LoLReplay, seemed to fix the issues that I was having.

The title of your post is somewhat misleading as no streaming actually happens - all that the link does is open LoLReplay on your local machine and pass in the details of the match you want to spectate.

This will only work for matches that are happening *now*, as it connects in a similar way as the LoL client does when you spectate a match.

### Calling LoLReplay from the browser

The links seem to be formatted as follows:

```
lrf://spectator [Observer IP Address][:Observer Port] [Observer Encryption Key] [Game Id] [Platform Id] [Client Version?]
```

`lrf://spectator` tells LoLReplay to open up in spectator mode.

`Observer IP Address` is required and can either be a hostname or an IP address. The hostname is usually in the format `spectator.[eu/na/br/etc.].lol.riotgames.com`.

`Observer Port` is optional, I believe it defaults to 8088 which appears to be the default spectator mode port.

`Observer Encryption Key`... is a required per-match encryption key.

`Game Id` is a required, per-match integer id.

`Platform Id` is a more specific version of the region, I guess relating to how Riot have grouped their servers. For example EUW1.

`Client Version`, the last field appears to be a version number - I can only assume this is either the version of the client that LoLReplay is using OR the version of the client the players in the match are using.

### How to find IP address, encryption key etc.

Edit: you can now grab all the info you need using the official Riot API, you just need the SummonerId of the user you're querying for. See [current-game](https://developer.riotgames.com/api/methods#!/976) API docs for usage.